# Update SQL Table with Text Area?

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

i'm trying to make it so that a user can type text in a textarea and then this updates the mysql table 'bio' within the database 'ptb_profiles'.

At the moment their information is being pulled into this textarea but i want it so that whatever they type in it updates the table.

I'm using the following code but it's not working? im new to php and mysql so it's bound to be wrong.

Any help would be really appreciated. thanks.

```
<?php 
//We check if the form has been sent
if(isset($_POST['bio']))
{
    $content = $_POST['bio'];
        //We remove slashes depending on the configuration
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
                $content = stripslashes($content);
        }
        //We check if all the fields are filled
        if($_POST['bio']!='')
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO ptb_profiles.bio VALUES (NULL, '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '".$message['bio']."');";
            mysql_query($sql, $connection);

            echo "<div class=\"infobox-message\">Your Profile Information has been updated..</div>";
        }
}

?>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">

<textarea id="bio"  rows="10" style="width: 456px; 
    margin-top:3px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:-2px;
    height: 122px;
    resize: none; 
    border: hidden;"><?php echo $profile['bio'] ?> </textarea>

     <input type="submit" name="send_button" id="send_button" value="Send">
```

Comment: What does 'it's not working' mean? Not writing anything to the database? Crashing the website? Writing the wrong information? Writing the right information to the wrong place?

Comment: i click submit and it just is dorment, does nothing. 0 null absolutely nothing. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your text area does not have the name="bio" property. Also use nl2br and htmlentities and then save in the database. And when getting it back get the real entities back.

```
     <?php 
//We check if the form has been sent
if(isset($_POST['bio']))
{
        echo $content = htmlentities(nl2br($_POST['bio']));
        //We remove slashes depending on the configuration


        //We check if all the fields are filled

            $sql = "INSERT INTO ptb_profiles.bio VALUES (NULL, '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '".$content."');";
            mysql_query($sql, $connection);

            echo "<div class=\"infobox-message\">Your Profile Information has been updated..</div>";
            //exit;

}


 $sql = "Select bio from ptb_profiles.bio WHERE user_id =  '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
 $res = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
 $profile = mysql_fetch_array($res);

 $nl = str_replace("<br />", "\n", $profile['bio']);
?>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">

<textarea id="bio" name="bio" rows="10" style="width: 456px; 
    margin-top:3px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:-2px;
    height: 122px;
    resize: none; 
    border: hidden;"><?php echo $nl; ?> </textarea>

     <input type="submit" name="send_button" id="send_button" value="Send">
```

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting content of `$message['bio']` but there's no `$message` array in your code (nor `$profile` you use to populate HTML below).

Also your `$content = stripslashes($content);` is pointless as you do not use `$content` any further, not to mention you should rather disable magic_quotes_gpc via PHP config or .htaccess instead of checking in the code.

Finally you are open for SQL injection attack.

EDIT: as spotted by @andrewsi, your `<textarea>` element lacks `name` as well.

Comment: His textarea field also doesn't have a `name` attribute, just an `id`; that might also be causing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

upon having this problem myself and spending some time trying to fix the problems with solutions from many many forum posts i managed to fix this same problem. Of all the forums i checked the problem was getting the string value from the textarea into an sql 'INSERT' statement using the $_POST php superglobal variable

the only way i can see that actually works and doesnt throw up any errors is to ignore the column names when writing the 'INSERT' statement so instead of:

```
"INSERT INTO tbl_dbTable ( Colummn1, Colummn2...) VALUES( '$_POST[textarea]', 'Value2'..)"
```

simply use:

```
"INSERT INTO tbl_dbTable VALUES( '$_POST[textarea]', 'Value2'..)"
```

The only downside is you MUST then list values for ALL the columns in the table, but it fixes the problem of getting the textarea value into an sql column.

hope this helps others having the same problem